# SSRS 2008 - Hidden row causing report to add extra page

Tags: ssrs-2008

Using SSRS 2008.

I've searched high and low for an answer for this but no one seems to have a similar problem.

I've got a report which works fine. It fits to 1 page and only goes over if some of the content in some of the rows grows to push it over 1 page. However, for the current data I'm using this doesn't occur and it sits on 1 page with plenty of room to spare.

I've now added another row, which is hidden based on a expression using a field within a dataset. The field contains either an "N" (indicating not to show the row) or a "Y" (don't hide row). When the row is hidden an extra blank page with footer appears at the end of the report. When the row is visible the extra page is no longer there and the report fits to 1 page again.

I've also tested this by removing the hidden expression (so inserting a blank row) and the report is only 1 page. So this tells me it's something to do with the visibility condition that's causing the extra blank page to appear.

Anyone got any pointers / help?

EDIT:

I've also tested this with simply selecting 'Hide' under 'Row Visibility...' rather than 'Show or Hide based on an expression'. This creates the same problem. I've also tried various ways of hiding the row manually by setting LineHeight to 1pt, CanGrow = True, CanShrink = True and then putting an expression into each cell in the row checking the above mentioned flag and returning "" if false (also tried Nothing). Row showed up in all cases as blank and had a default height. I also tried doing the same thing but editing the Xml, which gave the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the culprit. At some point through my various alterations I found that the rectangle container that contained the data tablix needed to be enlarged. I increased it by 0.3cm and it worked fine. What I still don't understand is why this was causing the report to create a second blank page when the row was HIDDEN (making the report smaller). My only guess would be that when the report was visible it was given a set height but when it was hidden (but presumably still populated) it didn't know how much space to allocate to the row or perhaps gave it a default height that was larger than what I gave it.